Can't get Mockito 5 Inject to work with Junit 4 after upgrade from Mockito 4
I have the following
@RequestMapping
public interface ExcludesOverriddenController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "excludes/overridden", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
  @ResponseBody
  @CsrfExempt
  String foo();
}
public class ExcludesOverriddenControllerImpl implements ExcludesOverriddenController {

  @Override
  public String foo() {
    return "Included due to excludes overridden property";
  }
}

and the following test
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestExcludesOverriddenControllerConfig.class})
public class ExcludesOverriddenControllerIntegrationTest {

  @Inject
  private ExcludesOverriddenControllerImpl exclOverriddenCtrlMock;

  ...
  @Before
  public void before() {
    ...
    when(exclOverriddenCtrlMock.foo()).thenReturn("Included due to excludes overridden property");
  }
  @Test
  public void testAccess() throws Exception {
mockMvc.perform(get("/excludes/overridden")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("Included due to excludes overridden property"));
  }
}
@Configuration
@LocalProfile
@Import(value = {WebMvcConfig.class, RootConfig.class, OtherConfiguration.class})
public class TestExcludesOverriddenControllerConfig {

  @Bean
  public Application application() {
    return new TestApplication();
  }

  @Bean
  public ExcludesOverriddenControllerImpl getExcludesOverriddenControllerImpl() {
    return mock(ExcludesOverriddenControllerImpl.class);
  }

  ...
}

When I run with Mockito 4 it works fine and passes but with version 5 the content is an empty string. What am I missing?

which Java version are you using?

I am using 17 @cyberbrain

What is @Inject? (It's not a Mockito annotation). SpringJUnit4ClassRunner does NOT create Mockito mock objects, but bootstraps your application context and injects (real) Spring beans. You can only call when on Mockito mocks/spies – your code should have never worked in the first place. Finally, a frame challenge: what exactly is your test supposed to test? You stub the method call with Mockito, then call it; so you are basically only testing that Mockito works correctly and nothing of your real code is tested.

@JGleason for further analysis, please add relevant parts of TestExcludesOverriddenControllerConfig (@knittl maybe Mockito mocks are configured in there and get injected by Spring?)

@cyberbrain ah yes, that's a valid point, a @MockBean could have been configured in the config. I wonder though why the method is stubbed, since the stubbed return value/behavior is the exact same as the actual, real implementation of the method.

Sorry for the delay guys I will post the requested today I was OOO

@cyberbrain Added as for what this is testing is a rest endpoint. The solution was to change the level we were mocking at so we were letting the test request get past the controller and just have it return its response without the mock given the functionality. I am more curious about why this is the case. Again if I run with Mockito 4 everything works as expected
